# Is it possible to reuse the logic defined in regex expression twice

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to reuse the logic defined in regex expression twice like

I want to match if Day range is defined like
`mon-wed` or `monday-friday`.

Here's regex expression used to match one day expression

```
/\b((mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b/
```

It works fine for `mon`, `tuesday` etc

but I want to reuse it to with `-` in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't want to just copy and paste the part you want repeated to form something like this:

```
\b((mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)-((mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b
```

You can store them as strings, then you concatenate the strings and finally, pass them into `new RegEx(...)`:

```
var partToBeRepeated = "\\b((mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\\b"
var regex = new RegEx(partToBeRepeated + "-" + partToBeRepeated)
```

Comment: yup I don't want to copy and paste the logic again

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

`\b((mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b-\b((mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b`

You can check [here](https://regexr.com/42f8i) for more